# How to save multiple custom user profile fields using repeater JQuery

Tags: custom-field, jquery, users, profiles

I'm trying to create a multiple custom user profile fields to allow our users adding more software skills in their profile page.

The problem I'm facing is it always saving only one meta for "`skills"` and one meta for `"skills_percent"` even if I added more inputs!

What should I do to save all of them when I adding more fields?

And how to display all of them as well in the front end!

[image]

here what I have done.

```
<table class="skills-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="skills"><?php _e("Skills"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
              <button type="button" class="add-field">+</button>        
              <div class="multi-fields">
                <div class="multi-field">
                  <input type="text" name="skills" id="skills" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'skills', $current_user->ID ) ); ?>" class="textbox" />
                  <input type="text" name="skills_percent" id="skills_percent" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'skills_percent', $current_user->ID ) ); ?>" class="textbox" /><br />
                  <button type="button" class="remove-field">-</button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your programs or software in the first box and how many percent in the second box ."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

script for `adding/removing` fields dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
});
</script>
```

updating the user meta

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['skills'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'skills', esc_attr( $_POST['skills'] ) );

if ( !empty( $_POST['skills_percent'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'skills_percent', esc_attr( $_POST['skills_percent'] ) );
```

displaying the author meta in the front end

```
<dt class="j-s-m">Skills</dt><dd class="text-intro"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('skills', $curauth->ID); ?> <?php echo get_the_author_meta('skills_percent', $curauth->ID); ?></dd>
```

> **Update 1** as mrben522 answer

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['skills'] ) )
    $skillArray = [];
if (is_array($_POST['skills'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['skills'] as $skill) {
        $skillArray[] = esc_attr($skill);
    }
} else {
    $skillArray[] = esc_attr($_POST['skills']);
}

    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'skills', $skillArray );


if ( !empty( $_POST['skills_percent'] ) )
    $skills_percentArray = [];
if (is_array($_POST['skills_percent'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['skills_percent'] as $skill_percent) {
        $skills_percentArray[] = esc_attr($skill_percent);
    }
} else {
    $skills_percentArray[] = esc_attr($_POST['skills_percent']);
}

    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'skills_percent', $skills_percentArray );
```

but it return Array Array for skills and skills percent, also not saving the second div of `"multi-field"`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add square brackets to input names to get PHP to interpret them as an array of data instead of overriding the value with each new input.

so your input will look like this:

```
          <input type="text" name="skills[]" id="skills" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'skills', $current_user->ID ) ); ?>" class="textbox" />
          <input type="text" name="skills_percent[]" id="skills_percent" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'skills_percent', $current_user->ID ) ); ?>" class="textbox" /><br />
```

And your sanitization will look like this (repeat the structure for `skills_percent`):

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['skills'] ) )
    $skillArray = [];
if (is_array($_POST['skills'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['skills'] as $skill) {
        if (!empty($skill)) {
            $skillArray[] = esc_attr($skill);
        }
    }
} else {
    $skillArray[] = esc_attr($_POST['skills']);
}

    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'skills', $skillArray );
```

EDIT:  You could also use `array_map` instead of a foreach loop.

`$skillArray = array_map('esc_attr', $_POST['skills']);`

EDIT 2:  Here's basic structure for looping over your data for showing the inputs.  I don't love this layout as it relies on the indices for the two arrays staying the same, but it should work.

```
<?php
$skills = get_the_author_meta( 'skills', $current_user->ID );
$skillPercents = get_the_author_meta( 'skills_percent', $current_user->ID );
if (is_array($skills) && is_array($skillPercents)) {
    foreach ($skills as $index => $skill) {
        ?>
        <div class="multi-field">
            <input type="text" name="skills[]" id="skills_<?php echo $index; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $skill ); ?>" class="textbox" />
            <input type="text" name="skills_percent[]" id="skills_percent_<?php echo $index; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $skillPercents[$index] ); ?>" class="textbox" /><br />
            <button type="button" class="remove-field">-</button>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
} else { ?>
    <div class="multi-field">
        <input type="text" name="skills[]" id="skills_0" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $skills ); ?>" class="textbox" />
        <input type="text" name="skills_percent[]" id="skills_percent_0" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $skillPercents ); ?>" class="textbox" /><br />
        <button type="button" class="remove-field">-</button>
    </div>
<?php   }
?>
```

You can rework this so each skill and percent was saved as it's own array in a 2d array to make it a bit more sturdy if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mrben522, kindly check the updated question.

Comment: You'll need to change your output as well.  `var_dump(get_the_author_meta( 'skills', $current_user->ID ));` and see what you get.  most likely it's going to be an array of data.  you'll need to create your input fields using a `foreach` loop iterating over that.

Comment: I'm sorry @mrben522, I still newbie, can you please give me a real answer so I can understand it as well, Thanks.

Comment: How can i foreach the input! :(

Comment: I can't see inputs any more, and add field button + not working :(

Comment: Try now, added fallbacks for if you don't have data in those meta fields yet

Comment: You are AMAZING, You make my day :), Last thing please, How can i call each input e.g ( skills+skills percent) for each software inside author profile, i tried this but not working! `<?php echo get_the_author_meta('skills', $curauth->ID); ?>` `<?php echo get_the_author_meta('skills_percent', $curauth->ID); ?>`

Comment: the meta should be an array, so you need to loop over it as such.  something like `foreach (get_the_author_meta('skills', $curauth->ID) as $skill) { echo $skill};`  although I would implement `!empty` and `is_array` checks before in case the data hasn't been set on an author

Comment: I hope i can give you million +1 Thanks so much.

Comment: I had a small issue, it saving inputs even they are empty!

Comment: I mean if I added more new field and all of them are empty, saving all of them as an empty div. How can i avoid that if the input are empty?

Comment: updated, added `if (!empty($skill) {...` to foreach loop

Comment: Thanks, yes i tried it before but the input disappears! as you said before because there is no any data yet. btw you forget one `)`  after `$skill` `if (!empty($skill) {...`

Comment: Hello @mrben522, I don't mean to bother you, Why when I added `if (!empty($skill)) ` to foreach loop the input fields disappearing?  Maybe there are problem with the `$skillArray[]` this is just guessing!